# Creating a directory in another drive (D:) with os module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-os

I want to create a directory with a specific path,  if it does not exist. But when the path is in another drive (D:), the dir is not created and I get the following message---> FileNotFoundError [WinError3] The system cannot find the path specified...[Complete trace of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coGR5.png)

[Even with os.chdir("D:"), still got error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNk1E.png)

The short code snippet, (The self.inputfile gives the path of a directory)

```
    if not os.path.exists(f"{self.inputfile}/output"):
        os.makedirs(f"{self.inputfile}/output")
```

Edit: In my case I was trying to create a directory, but one of the subdirs ended with .zip, which was causing the error, after removing that, everything worked fine, using os.chdir wasn't necessary

Comment: Is it a network drive?

Comment: no it's another drive on my pc

Comment: @EdrisJ Please edit your question and show the complete traceback.

Comment: thanks, I just added it